# Is there an idiomatic way to check for the existence of a variant in a Vec?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have the following enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  One(u64),
  Two(u64),
  Three(u64)
}
```

If I have a `Vec<MyEnum>` and I only want to check if a kind of variant exists, without caring about the value it contains, is there a better way to check this without resorting to this:

```
let my_enums: Vec<MyEnum> = vec![];
my_enums.push(MyEnum::One(1));
my_enums.push(MyEnum::Two(2));

let two_exists = my_enums.iter().any(|x| match x {
   MyEnum::Two(_) => true,
   _ => false,
});
```

The value in the variant is important later, but not in this check specifically. It feels like a lot of syntax to check if this variant exists.

Comment: Take a look at [matches!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) macro.

Comment: Apart from that `Iterator::any` is fine. If you find yourself writing it often, you can section this off to a new function.

Comment: You can also add `.is_two()` etc. methods to `MyEnum` (using `matches!` as the above comment points out) and then you can do `.any(|x| x.is_two())` or `.any(MyEnum::is_two)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have already pointed out:

- If the property of being `Two` (henceforth known as "The Twoness") is rarely important, and only checked at this one site, you can simply use `matches!` directly in the `.any()`-closure.
- If The Twoness, The Oneness, and/or The Threeness is inspected at many sites, it is idiomatic Rust to have methods on `MyEnum` whose only job it is to return a `bool` if the current value is of a certain variant. That is, you'd have `MyEnum::is_one() -> bool`, `MyEnum::is_two() -> bool`, etc.

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    One(u64),
    Two(u64),
    Three(u64),
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn is_two(&self) -> bool {
        matches!(self, Self::Two(_))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_enums: Vec<MyEnum> = vec![];
    my_enums.push(MyEnum::One(1));
    my_enums.push(MyEnum::Two(2));

    // More code at the site where The Twoness is checked
    assert!(my_enums.iter().any(|x| matches!(x, MyEnum::Two(_))));

    // The Twoness is more of an inheriant property of `MyEnum`,
    // more code in the `impl`, less code at the site where The
    // Twoness is checked.
    assert!(my_enums.iter().any(MyEnum::is_two))
}
```

Comment: strum can synthesize these `is_*` methods for you with [`EnumIs`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.EnumIs.html).